# NSarray count throwing out of bounds

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I am trying to check the following and all throw an out of bounds error

```
if ([objects count] < 1)
if ([objects count] == 0)
if ([objects count] <= 0)
```

All three thrown an out of bounds? How do I use this in an "if/else" statement? Is it not possible to check if an NSArray contains zero objects.

Comment: What class is `objects`?  What are you doing inside the `if` block with `objects`?  Maybe it is something in there causing the exception?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Out of Bounds Exception on NSArray thats Empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255626/out-of-bounds-exception-on-nsarray-thats-empty)

Comment: `objects` is an object of what class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just defined the pointer but did not initialize your `objects` instance, you will get very strange behavior. As a beginning cocoa developer, I got burned at least twice by something like

```
NSMutableArray *objects;
...
if ( [objects count] == 0 )
{
    .... // do something 
}
```

Are you sure you initialized it, e.g. like so:

```
NSMutableArray *objects = [NSMutableArray array];
```

because it really should work in that case!

Comment: Overlooked it. Damn the small things!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that these lines of code can cause such an error.

This code will work correctly for any array. 
Out of bounds exception means that you tried to call something like

```
[myArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

On an empty array. Or, in other words, you tried to access an object that wasn't a part of the array.

Comment: Please refrain from using abbreviations here on stack overflow. They are frowned upon as they give your post a sense of unprofessionalism. I have taken the liberty to removing them from your post.

Answer (score 0):

You should not get an out of bounds exception since you are not even trying to access an element in the array -- an out of bounds exception should only be thrown if you call `objectAtIndex` on your array and specify an illegal index.

In general, to prevent against attempting to access a nil or empty array, I usually do something like this:

```
if(!objects || !objects.count) ...
```

This way, if `objects` doesn't exist then `objects.count` will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
if(![objects lastObject])
{
    //... Do Something
}
```